# cronjob isnt working

Tags: cron

I have the following crontab set up:

```
00 00 * * * clamscan -r / --move /var/infected
*/5 * * * * /var/www/sitzungspause.de/rename.sh
*/5 * * * * /var/www/besprechungspause.de/rename.sh

cron start/running, process 952
```

rename.sh:

```
rm /var/www/sitzungspause.de/public_html/sugar/SugarCE622/ajax.php.1
mv /var/www/sitzungspause.de/public_html/sugar/SugarCE622/ajax.php /var/www/sitzungspause.de/public_html/sugar/SugarCE622/ajax.php.1
```

respectively for the other site

`ajax.php` contains potential virus code, that replicates itself every day. Renaming it is my "way to fo fight it", because I cannot figure out where it comes from.

Comment: best not to post dangerous code. Could you clarify what is not working? Because I suspect `clamscan` is not in `cron`'s PATH, but I guess the other jobs should run OK...

Comment: nope. none of the three jobs are working. how could I get clamcscan to work?

Comment: well, if it is a path problem, you would use the full path to it: run `which clamscan` and then use whatever it says in the command, like `/usr/local/bin/clamscan -r` or whatever. But if none of them are running then maybe that is not it